# GPT Protective Partition encrypted by Truecrypt

Tags: external-hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, gpt, partition-recovery

I have a Seagate 4Tb 2.5" HDD.
I partitioned this drive into three and encrypted two parts with Truecrypt.
Sadly the USB 3 micro type b jack broke away from the drive just as I was backing everything up onto the cloud.
I've mounted the drive into an external universal 2.5" caddy. The computer see's it but it won't mount and it now shows in the disk management tool as a single healthy GPT Protective Partition with 16,384 Gb of space.
Usually when I plug this drive in windows tells me that it's unformatted, which I ignore and mount with Trucrypt.
I don't get this prompt anymore and Truecrpt doesn't see the volume if I try to mount it.
Is there a way to get my computer to see the drive again so I can mount it with Trucrypt?
I've tried it on a linux machine as well, but that doesn't see it either.
I've ordered another identical caddy to the one the drive broke from, in case this helps.
Most of the data is backed up but there is some I really don't want to lose.

Thanks

Comment: 16,384 GB would be approximately 16 TB sounds like a problem with the caddy

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the new caddy when it arrives.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was to buy a new empty Seagate 2.5" case, from ebay, complete with the USB 3 micro type b jack chipboard interface. Once the Seagate hard drive was attached to a Seagate chipboard interface, it worked perfectly again. The encryption wasn't an issue and the drive mounted normally again.